# Is the polynomial $p^{2k+2} - 4p^{k+2} + 6p^{k+1} - 4p^k + 1$ a square for integers $k \neq 1$ and $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, factoring, square-numbers

My initial question in the present post is pretty basic:

> Is the (integer) polynomial $$p^{2k+2} - 4p^{k+2} + 6p^{k+1} - 4p^k + 1$$ a square for integers $k \neq 1$ and $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, and primes $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$?

When $k=1$, I know that this polynomial is equal to
$$p^4 - 4p^3 + 6p^2 - 4p + 1 = (p - 1)^4$$
which is a square.  I am interested in the cases when $k \neq 1$ and $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

Already, when $k=5$, we have the rather curious-looking factorization
$$p^{12} - 4p^7 + 6p^6 - 4p^5 + 1$$
$$= (p - 1)^2 \cdot \bigg(p^{10} + 2p^9 + 3p^8 + 4p^7 + 5p^6 + 2p^5 + 5p^4 + 4p^3 + 3p^2 + 2p + 1\bigg).$$

So I am led to conjecture that:

> **CONJECTURE A:** The (integer) polynomial $$p^{2k+2} - 4p^{k+2} + 6p^{k+1} - 4p^k + 1$$ is not a square for $k \neq 1$ and $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

**Alas, I have no proof for this conjecture.**

**FINAL QUESTION** Can you prove *Conjecture A*?

Comment: $k=1$ is the only positive integer for which it is a square. In fact, if $k>1$ it is enough to compare it with $(p^{k+1} -2p +a)^2$ for $a=2,3$

Comment: Sorry, @Exodd, but how are you getting your required conclusion for $k > 1$ in this [previous comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4460448/is-the-polynomial-p2k2-4pk2-6pk1-4pk-1-a-square-for-integ?noredirect=1#comment9344588_4460448)?

Comment: Got it, @Exodd!

Computing the pairwise differences:
$$\bigg(p^{2k+2} - 4p^{k+2} + 6p^{k+1} - 4p^k + 1\bigg) - \bigg(p^{k+1} - 2p + 2\bigg)^2 = 2p(p - 2)(p^{k-1} - 2) - 3$$
and
$$\bigg(p^{k+1} - 2p + 3\bigg)^2 - \bigg(p^{2k+2} - 4p^{k+2} + 6p^{k+1} - 4p^k + 1\bigg) = 4\bigg(p^k + (p - 3)p + 2\bigg),$$
**both** of which are **positive**.

Comment: This implies that
$$\bigg(p^{k+1} - 2p + 2\bigg)^2 < \bigg(p^{2k+2} - 4p^{k+2} + 6p^{k+1} - 4p^k + 1\bigg) < \bigg(p^{k+1} - 2p + 3\bigg)^2,$$
which means that $\bigg(p^{2k+2} - 4p^{k+2} + 6p^{k+1} - 4p^k + 1\bigg)$ cannot be a square if $k > 1$, since in that case it is (strictly) in-between two consecutive squares.

Comment: @Exodd: Sorry for the bother (and the late revert), but if I may just ask - How did you compute for $(p^{k+1} - 2p + a)^2$ (for $a = 2, 3$) as the correct polynomial for comparison to the one I am considering?  Mind sharing a reference for the said computation, if you have one?

Comment: It's a classical "complete the square" approach. I couldn't find a reference that explains it for generic polynomials, but the approach is the same as for the quadratics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to [Exodd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4460448/is-the-polynomial-p2k2-4pk2-6pk1-4pk-1-a-square-for-integ#comment9344588_4460448)'s comment, I am hereby posting this answer, so that this question does not remain in the unanswered queue.

---

Computing the pairwise differences
$$\left(p^{2k+2} - 4p^{k+2} + 6p^{k+1} - 4p^k + 1\right) - \left(p^{k+1} - 2p + 2\right)^2 = 2p(p-2)(p^{k-1} - 2) - 3$$
and
$$\left(p^{k+1} - 2p + 3\right)^2 - \left(p^{2k+2} - 4p^{k+2} + 6p^{k+1} - 4p^k + 1\right) = 4\left(p^k + (p - 3)p + 2\right),$$
both of which are **positive** for prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and positive $k>1$ satisfying $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

This implies that
$$\left(p^{k+1} - 2p + 2\right)^2 < \left(p^{2k+2} - 4p^{k+2} + 6p^{k+1} - 4p^k + 1\right) < \left(p^{k+1} - 2p + 3\right)^2$$
which means that $f(p,k)=p^{2k+2} - 4p^{k+2} + 6p^{k+1} - 4p^k + 1$ cannot be a square if $p$ is a prime satisfying $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $k>1$ is such that $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, since in this case $f(p,k)$ is strictly in-between two consecutive squares.